# Entity Framework EntityKey / Foreign Key problem

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity, entitykey

As the result of a form post, I'm trying to save a new Brand record. In my view, Gender is a dropdown, returning an Integer, which is populated from ViewData("gender")

I've setup my link as follows:

```
gID = CInt(Request.Form("Gender"))
Brand.GenderReference.EntityKey = New EntityKey("DB_ENTITIES.Gender", "Id", gID)
TryUpdateModel(Brand)
DB.SaveChanges()
```

Which results in the following error.

```
Entities in 'DB_ENTITIES.Brand' participate in the 'FK_Brand_Gender' relationship. 0 related 'Gender' were found. 1 'Gender' is expected.
```

Could someone explain the parameters in plain english to me. I've also tried DB.Gender as the first parameter but no joy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than creating an EntityKey create a stub Gender object
(sorry I'm not a VB guy so in C#):

```
Gender g = new Gender{ID = Int32.Parse(Request.Form("Gender"))};
```

Then you attach the Gender to the appropriate `EntitySet` (the name of property on `DB` that you get Gender entities from is the string below):

```
DB.AttachTo("Genders",g);
```

This puts the database in the state where the Gender is in the `ObjectContext` in the unchanged state without a database query. Now you can build a relationship as per normal

```
brand.Gender = g;
DB.AddToBrand(brand);
DB.SaveChanges();
```

That is all there is to it. No need to muck around with `EntityKeys`

Hope this helps

[Alex](http://twitter.com/adjames)

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex - getting this now:

An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Comment: Paul, how did you solve the 'multiple objects with the same key' issue? I am getting the same.

Comment: Before attaching something to the context you should check the ObjectStateManager using LINQ to Objects to check that the same object isn't already there.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an instance of both Brand and Gender and then set Brand.Gender to the instance of the Gender. Then you can save without problems.

Comment: Does that not involve a round trip to my DB? Surely the View is posting back an ID that can be tied up.

Comment: It depends, if the objects are already in the context, it does not require a trip to the db. Alex James code is good to use (it pretty much does as I wrote).

Answer (score 0):

Ok heres what I've come up with instead of using updateModel. It appears to be problematic / potentially a security risk anyway with potentially additional fields being added in the post. A New instance of Gender can be instantiated via trygetObjectByKey. This is working so far. Any other suggestions on getting UpdateModel to update the Gender property object appreciated.

```
Dim cID As Integer
cID = CInt(Request.Form("Gender"))
Dim key As New EntityKey(DB.DefaultContainerName() & ".Gender", "ID", cID)

Dim objGenderDS As New Gender
'Bring back the Gender object.
If DB.TryGetObjectByKey(key, objGenderDS) Then
Brand.GenderReference.EntityKey = key
Brand.Gender = objGenderDS
DB.AddToBrand(Brand)
DB.SaveChanges()
Else
End If
```