# Entities in 'table 2' participate in the 'foreign key' relationship.0 related 'table 1' were found

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, edmx

I am currently working on the entity framework in .NET. When I try the save mu changed entities by calling the 'SaveChanges' method. It gives me the error :

Entities in 'Table 2' participate in the 'FK_Table2_Table1' relationship. 
0 related 'Table1' were found. 1 'Table1' is expected.

When I have generated the entity model from the database and also the .edmx file shows me the relationship between these two tables,why does this error occur.

Comment: Did you check solution presented here-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011519/entity-framework-entitykey-foreign-key-problem